# How to initialize a struct with both a mutable and an immutable field?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

All the examples of structs I've read thus far are either when all fields are mutable or all fields are immutable. Thus, this compiles fine:

```
[<Struct>]
type Number(x:int) =
    member this.X = x
```

And so does this:

```
[<Struct>]
type Number =
    val mutable X:int
    new(x) = {X = x}
```

However, I do not know how to write an explicit constructor for a struc that has one field mutable and one immutable:

```
[<Struct>]
type Numbers(x:int) =
    member this.X = x
    val mutable Y:int
    new(x,y) = ???
```

The explicit constructor must clearly call the implicit one. All the naive solutions I've tried thus far have failed.

A follow-up question: does the solution, whatever it is, assign the field Y once or twice (first with the default value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicit construction syntax used in your second example works for all structs, whether they have mutable fields or not.

We could also rewrite the first example to use that syntax, although it's less nice looking. There's also a technical difference in that `member this.X` defines a property whereas `val X` defines a field.

In the third case you'd write this:

```
[<Struct>]
type Numbers =
    val X : int
    val mutable Y : int
    new(x, y) = { X = x; Y = y }
```

This only explicitly assigns `Y` once.

Comment: Thanks! Do `val X` and `member this.X` differ only in the constructors used? If so, why does Microsoft say "Explicit fields are not intended for routine use" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494.aspx ?

Comment: Actually, `member this.X` is a /property/, not a field - though the compiler will end up putting the constructor argument `x` in a field so that the property implementation can access it. So they are two quite different things, even though they look the same. I should have mentioned this in my answer, I'll edit it.